# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installed on USB key Sandisk 128 G 3.0 --- Using CLONEZILLA for backup

Tags: 16.04, usb, backup, ssd, clonezilla

I made a backup of my OS and put it on a 1TB HDD WD MyPassport. Can I use this backup on the same machine, but to put the backup for example on a NEW SSD? Without having any problem or is it not a nice thing to do or in other words is it impossible that this function because maybe there's a different machine ID? Or other? Any suggestion would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

- You can restore a cloned backup (in this case an image made with Clonezilla) into a drive of exactly the same size or bigger (but not one single byte smaller), so you cannot restore from the 128 GB USB key to a 120 GB SSD.
- Please check with

  ```
  sudo parted -ls
  ```

  that the drives have the same physical sector size. Otherwise there will be problems.
- If an MSDOS partition table, the cloned copy will work at once.
- If a GUID partition table, GPT, there is a backup partition table at the tail end of the drive. If the target drive is not exactly the same size as the source drive, you must repair that backup partition table, and it can be done with `gdisk` or with the [shellscript `gptfix`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS/stable-alternative#gpt-fix), that uses `gdisk`.